# Downloading static high resolution images using Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-api

I wanted to download some high resolution (<5m) images. I have their co-ordinates and viewed them on https://earth.google.com/web/ and it's exactly what I want. I have approximately 300 such images to download. I was wondering, how can I do this with Python?

I checked out the Google Earth API but I am not sure which dataset to choose from the catalog to get the same images from the web version. Any idea as to how I can do this?

Comment: The terms allow you use the imagery in Google Earth (Web/Pro or Engine). But not outside of those applications. You will need to seek an alternative or paid for service to get high-resolution images. It costs money to launch satellites and aircraft to capture these images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Google Satellite Map downloader? Its paid desktop app (Like a backdoor) you can use to download Google Earth imagery with an appreciable high resolution and in TIFF format. Although I'm not sure if it's in agreement with Google terms and condition.

Or you could use Global Mapper by loading the Coordinates of the area you're interested in and clicking find data online>>Satellite imagery >>Google Earth imagery.